# Which event in the app's startup sequence is appropriate to trigger loading a config file in AIR/Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, configuration, air, initialization

I am working on a small AIR desktop application and I have some configuration infos that I want to store in a little file that's loaded at some point when the application starts and will be used to set public properties on the root application object. This should work just as if I had public variables declared in an <mx:Script> block at the beginning of my main MXML file.

I seem to have the choice of three events that could be used to initiate loading the configuration file:

- invoke
- initialize
- creationComplete

Did I overlook some more? Which one is appropriate and why? Does it matter at all?

Example issues that come to my mind are:

- are all components already accessible or will I get NULL references?
- will some of my settings be overwritten in a phase that's coming after the event?

There's probably more.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your handler needs to access UI components directly, you should wait for `creationComplete`; otherwise you'll get NULL references.

If you simply want to set properties on the root `Application` object, `initialize` seems the best place to do this.  If you wait until `creationComplete`, and if the properties that you set are bound to your controls, then you might get a run-time resize or flicker as those components are updated.